# How to close popup when click anywhere in website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to close popup ad when user click anywhere in body.

This is my site http://daplonline.in/. I want to hide or close ad when user click anywhere in website.

This is popup html code:

```
<div style="top: 100px; background-color: rgba(5, 5, 0, 0.7); display: block;" id="wd1_nlpopup" data-expires="30" data-delay="10">
    <div id="overlay">
        <a href="#closepopup" id="wd1_nlpopup_close">x</a>
        <div class="content">  
            <a href="buyonline.php"><img src="images/online_course.gif"/></a>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

This is JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").click(function(){
        alert("me");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @PragneshChauhan answer is not enough please check my code

Comment: @vivek see my answer....you need to add click event handler for overlay...not for body...

Comment: With event delegation you would not even need an overlay and could just check that your popup is NOT clicked, which means anything outside must have been clicked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Check this code 100% working and tested.. :)**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').click(function() {

     $('#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').hide();
     $('#wd1_nlpopup').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: your code is working i added the 

`<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function(){
       $('#wd1_nlpopup').hide();
    $('#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').hide();
    });
});
</script>`

and works fine thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit your selector to below,

```
$(function(){
   $("#wd1_nlpopup_overlay").click(function(){
      alert("me");
   });
})
```

because actually you are clicking on overlay not on body.

Now as this popup might get load later so you need to delegate event handler as below,

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on('click',"#wd1_nlpopup_overlay",function(){
        alert("me");
    });
})
```

Comment: thank you but not working i can's see and alert i want to close ad when user click anywhere in body not the close popup image

Comment: @vivek see event delegation code and try...and as i said your overlay is hiding body behind so you need to add code for overlay click....

Comment: @vivek well well well you have `TypeError: $mainmenu.parent(...).get(...) is undefined` error in `console` see your console..

Answer (score 1):

What it seems to me to give a click event to the close popup btn. You can do it this way:

```
$("#wd1_nlpopup_overlay").click(function(){
   $("#wd1_nlpopup_close").click(); // <--this will fire an event to the closebtn
});
```

Comment: I like this approach of triggering the click event of the close button better than my solution (which was to hide).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are forgetting the jQuery document initialiser. try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function(){
      $("#wd1_nlpopup_close").click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('body').on('click', function(event){
    var popup = $('#wd1_nlpopup');
    if($(event.target).not(popup)){
        $(popup).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or remove popup using

```
$('#your-id').hide();
```

or

```
$("#your-id").remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/xpkFf/ it will remove popup if will click anywhere

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});



$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false
});

// Close Pop-in If the user clicks anywhere else on the page
             jQuery('html') //set for html for jsfiddle, but should be 'body'
              .bind(
               'click',
               function(e){
            if(
             jQuery('#dialog').dialog('isOpen')
             && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
             && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
            ){
             jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            }
               }
              );
```